# Modify New() constructor on System.Data.DataTable

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to declare a DataTable and inicialize it at the same time:
Assuming sqlInstance.GetDataTable() returns a DataTable

Instead of doing this:

```
Dim dtTable as New DataTable()
dtTable = sqlclassInstance.GetDataTable()
```

Use one neat line, for the sake of saving code lines :)

```
Dim dtTable as New DataTable(sqlInstance.GetDataTable())
```

Or something like this:

```
Dim dtTable as New DataTable() = sqlclassInstance.GetDataTable()
```

Using explicit and strict on.
Heard of extension method usage I don't know if it applies to this, I'm kinda noobish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to **assign** the variable:

```
Dim dtTable as DataTable = sqlclassInstance.GetDataTable()
```

Since you don't want to create a new instance, you don't want to use the `New` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `sqlInstance.GetDataTable()` returns a DataTable:

```
Dim dt as DataTable = sqlInstance.GetDataTable()
```

Comment: No problem. You got two answers within a minute of eachother!  :)